# install apc on php 5.5

Tags: php, apc, php-5.5

I have been able to install apc on php 5.3 but recently I upgraded to
php 5.5 fpm and I cant seem to install it:

```
Error: Package: php-pecl-apc-3.1.9-2.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.5.27-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
               php(api) = 20121113-64
.....
.....
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

This is what I see. Isn't there an apc version for php 5.5 or

Thank you!

Comment: PHP >=5.5 comes with OpCache, which replaces APC for opcode caching.... if you need to use APCs equivalent of user data caching, then use [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu) instead

Comment: Oh thanks. Apparently apcu is already installed.

Answer (score 4):

APC is dead and unmaintained.
No stable version exists for PHP 5.4 or greater.

As said by mark, you can use:

- php-opcache, for opcode cache, which is the official cache, maintained inside PHP
- php-pecl-apcu, for user data cache, which is a dropin replacement (same API) of APC.